# mod_python with apache2, (Re)importing module error

Tags: apache2, mod-python, cgi-bin

I'm trying to get mod-python to work with apache2 but not having any success. I've followed a few tutorials for getting mod-python working but I can't see what I'm doing wrong.

When I visit http://site.example.com/cgi-bin/test.py I actually get my 404 page! (whereas I get a 403 forbidden if the file really doesn't exist)

Here's my setup:

In /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/ there are configuration files named after each of my domains. In [the site.example.com file](http://dpaste.com/hold/21618/) I've added this to the user directives section:

```
# Begin user directives <--
<Directory /home/default/site.example.com/user/htdocs/cgi-bin/>
     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
     AllowOverride AuthConfig
     Order allow,deny
     allow from all
     AddHandler mod_python .py
     PythonHandler mod_python.publisher
     PythonDebug On
</Directory>
# --> End user directives
```

full file [here](http://dpaste.com/hold/21618/), which includes the line:

**EDIT** to add contents of test.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/python  
print "Content-type: text/html"  
print  
print 'hello world'  
#print 1/0
```

As shown above, I get a `404 /python/test.py was not found on this server`.

But if I uncomment the last line I get:

```
Mod_python error: "PythonHandler mod_python.publisher"

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/mod_python/apache.py", line 299, in HandlerDispatch
    result = object(req)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/mod_python/publisher.py", line 98, in handler
    path=[path])

  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/mod_python/apache.py", line 457, in import_module
    module = imp.load_module(mname, f, p, d)

  File "/home/default/site.example.co.uk/user/htdocs/python/test.py", line 5, in ?
    print 1/0

ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
```

Does this traceback look right? Enabling cgitb has no effect by the way.

Is there any other info I can add to help diagnose this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, the Publisher handler needs to take in a request object and a method in order to return the response.

In my scripts, I have something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python  
def run(req):
  return 'Hello world!'
```

Then, go to http://.../python/test.py/run

In this case, req is the request object that gets passed in by the Publisher Handler.

And, in case you don't have one already, you need to have an `__init__.py` file in the same directory where test.py is.

Also, with the Publisher, I noticed that sometimes, the response gets cached. I will get the same errors back in the browser that I had already fixed. So, it's not a bad idea to restart apache if you see an error that you think you fixed already.

Comment: Ok brill that works now! Thanks.
With the server based python I've used in the past you just print your output to the user. What are the different options for PythonHandler? Which of them was I using when I printed straight to output (including headers)? Don't think it was PSP. Python as CGI script?

Comment: Well, it could either have been Python as a CGI script, or the CGI Handler in mod_python. They're pretty much the same. If you want to use mod_python in that way, use this in your Apache conf file instead: 

PythonHandler mod_python.cgihandler

Then, your normal python CGI scripts should work.

Comment: +1  . I had PythonHandler mod_python.publisher. Had to change it to PythonHandler mod_python.cgihandler to make python scripts work as cgi.

Answer (score 2):

For starters, I would suggest not using the `cgi-bin` directory because that's intended for CGI scripts. Python files that get loaded with mod_python are not CGI scripts. (Theoretically you should be able to load Python files from the `cgi-bin` directory, but it'll be easier to debug if you give your Python files their own directory.)

Now, your document root is `/home/default/site.example.com/user/htdocs` so I'd suggest creating a subdirectory of that, say `/home/default/site.example.com/user/htdocs/python`, to put your Python files in - just for testing. Don't create any `Alias` or `ScriptAlias` directives for this directory (because it's under the document root already), but you'll need to put something like this in your virtual host file:

```
<Directory /home/default/site.example.com/user/htdocs/python/>
     Order allow,deny
     Allow from all
     AddHandler mod_python .py
     PythonHandler mod_python.publisher
     PythonDebug On
</Directory>
```

.Move the file `test.py` to that directory and try going to `http://site.example.com/python/test.py`, and you should see the results of the `index` function in the file `test.py`.

Comment: Thanks, just tried that, I get this wierd error mode: if the script has as error it's shown; script has no error... raises 404!

Comment: How about posting the contents of test.py? (edit it into your question)

Answer (score 2):

The python file should look like this in order to get the desired output:

```
def index():
  return "hello world"
```

"http://somesite.com/path/test.py" opens the function "index" by default.

"http://somesite.com/path/test.py/run" opens the function "run" instead.

You can get fancier, but the above will give you a basic mod_python page.